# Find italic paragraph text after h2 tag HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I want to grab all ***italic and bold*** text (song names) after all **h2** tags. here is html code

```
<h2>"Artist Name 1"></h2>

<p><br><b><i>Song Name 1</i>.</b> 2008.
<br><b>Music</b> Name Name
<br><b>Lyrics:</b> Name Name

<p><b><i>Song Name 2</i></b> 2008.
<br><b>Music</b> Name Name
<br><b>Lyrics:</b> Name Name

<h2>"Artist Name 2"></h2>

<p><br><b><i>Song Name 1</i>.</b> 2009.
<br><b>Music</b> Name Name
<br><b>Lyrics:</b> Name Name

<p><b><i>Song Name 2</i></b> 2009.
<br><b>Music</b> Name Name
<br><b>Lyrics:</b> Name Name

...
```

I tried something like this in c#

```
string Url = "url/page.html";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2");
if (headers != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode item in headers)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(item.InnerText + "\n");

        }
}
```

I can grab all **h2** text (Artist Names). but i need a little help to continue the code.

Comment: `<h2>"Artist Name 2"></h2>` - That seems a wrong HTML. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @PraveenKumar there is a mistake. please ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IT is very simple I change this:

```
var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2");
```

to this:

```
 var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//b/i");
```

It is tested and it is wokrs.

Gets only song name:

Result:

```
Song name 1

Song name 2
```

If You want something more complex like artist name and his/her songs. It is works.

```
    var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2");

    if (headers != null)
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode item in headers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText); //Artist Name

            var next = item.NextSibling;

            while (next != null)
            {
                if (next.FirstChild != null && next.FirstChild.Name == "i")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(next.InnerText); //Song Name for artist
                }

                if (next.Name == "h2")
                {
                    break;
                }

                next = next.NextSibling;
            }
        }
    }
```

Result is:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to say. I want to categories 'songs' under artist. (Ex: **Artist Name 1** - song name 1, song name 2 **Artist Name 2** song name 1, song name 2) that's why i think to use for loop. could you please enhance the code to doing that requirement

Comment: @JumRemdesk Moment, pls

Comment: @JumRemdesk OK I update my answer and solusion is wokring as You want